# Summing cumulative area under curves of overapping triangles

Tags: matlab, sum, area

I have two matrices for several triangles:

```
x =

    2.0000    5.0000   10.0000
    8.0000   10.0000   12.0000
   12.0000   24.0000   26.0000
   22.0000   25.0000   28.0000
   23.0000   26.0000   25.0000
   23.5000   27.0000   27.5000
   20.0000   23.0000   27.0000
   21.0000   24.0000   27.0000
   24.0000   25.0000   27.0000
   24.0000   26.0000   27.0000
   24.0000   28.0000   29.0000
   19.0000   22.0000   25.0000
   18.0000   21.0000   23.0000


y =

         0    1.0000         0
         0    0.8000         0
         0    0.6000         0
         0    0.8000         0
         0    0.8000         0
         0    0.8000         0
         0    1.0000         0
         0    1.0000         0
         0    1.0000         0
         0    1.0000         0
         0    1.0000         0
         0    1.0000         0
         0    1.0000         0
```

one line is one triangle. Columns are x and y positions of each point of the triangles.

So, I plot all these triangles and I need to sum the cumulative area under the curve of the triangles.

I try to use the `area` function, but I couldn't find how to sum their areas.

EDIT: I need to plot the sum of the areas on a red line in the same graphics. So I don't want a number like 20 cm²... I would like something like that:

[image]

Comment: Your edit makes very little sense... please elaborate (preferably with a manually drawn image)

Comment: I would like something like that : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71431809/FAC/Stage_M1/plot_triangle.png

Comment: @That just gives me a dropbox 404 error? Nevermind, you just need to edit and remove the [link] from your URL please

Comment: I've added the image to your question. Please provide some sample data (say for just the first two triangles?)

Comment: Also can you guarantee that all the triangles will have two vertices on the x-axis?

Comment: I edit with some data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you interpolate to create all your individual triangles and then add the results. First you will need to augment your `x` and `y` matrices with the beginning (the origin) and end points like so:

```
m = 30; %// This is your max point, maybe set it using max(x(:))?
X = [zeros(size(x,1),1), x, ones(size(x,1),1)*m];
Y = [zeros(size(y,1),1), y, zeros(size(y,1),1)];
```

then perform all the interpolations (I'll sum as I go):

```
xi = 0:0.1:m;
A = zeros(1,size(xi,2)); %// initialization
for row = 1:size(x,1)
    A = A + interp1(X(row,:), Y(row,:), xi);
end
```

and finally plot:

```
plot(x,y,'k')
hold on
plot(xi,A,'r','linewidth',2)
```

using your example data this gives:

[image]

Comment: well, I would like to sum the triangles on a plot. Someting like that: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71431809/FAC/Stage_M1/plot_triangle.png

Comment: So you want the cumulative area under the curve - your question does not do a good job of explaining that at all! I think you should reword it...

Comment: You could add the origin and the point x=0;y=30 to all your rows, then do a linear interpolation on each and then sum all the results...

Comment: Ok, I try to make an interpolation for all the x_position

Comment: @Lionel see my edit, I've updated the answer to match your edits

Comment: Well... How could I sum all the results ? (I interpolate the data) I still have 13 lines in matrix x and y corresponding to the 13 triangles. So, `cumsum` and `sum` give me an error : `Dimension argument must be a positive integer scalar within indexing range.`

Comment: Ok I didn't see it. Thank's, I try this :)

Comment: Wow, it's exactly what I need. I trying this but I have this : `Error using  + 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
    A = A + interp1(X(row,:), Y(row,:), xi);` I'm looking for this error (certainly my bad)

Comment: Check that you have the most recent edit of this line: `A = zeros(1,size(xi,2))`. Originally I had it as `size(x,..` instead of `size(xi,...` which would cause the error you're getting

Comment: yep, at x=29 there is a problem. Even if I change `m=35`. At x=29, that should be 0

Comment: The error is because your 5th triangle "leans" over (i.e. the middle point has a larger x value than the third point - 26>25) this kind of complicates things so if it's not an error in your data then this method is not accurate for your purposes :/

Comment: I change this. It was my bad

Comment: Thank's a lot again ! :)

Comment: @Lionel if this answered your question make sure to check the checkmark at the top of the answer!